# Force angular component to reload on back button press

Tags: angular, routes, back

I have a TeamSeasonComponent which has a url of `http://localhost:4200/teams/season/<team_id>`. On that page, there are links to other team's which would navigate to `http://localhost:4200/teams/season/team_2_id>`. I route between those two pages using a function:

```js
export function routeToTeamSeason(team_season_id: string): void{
    localStorage.clear()
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/', {skipLocationChange: true}).then(()=>
        this.router.navigate(['/teams/season', team_season_id])
    )
}
```

This all works as expected. The issue I'm having is if I navigate from `team_1's` page to `team_2's` page, and then press the back button on my browser, the URL updates with `team_1's` `team_season_id`, but the component does not refresh and `team_2's` data is still displayed. If I then refresh the page, it reloads with `team_1's` data.

How can I force a page refresh any time the URL changes? I have a few components that will have this issue, so if I can make some global rule that always reloads any component if the URL changes, that would be ideal. Otherwise, how can I implement a rule like that for a specific component?

Answer (score 6):

Of course I find an answer 5 minutes after posting. I was able to set a global rule to reload my a component any time a back/forward button gets pressed with this:

```js
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
  location.reload()
}
```

Just had to put that in my app.component.ts, and all it's children components will now call a `location.reload()` any time a window:popstate occurs.

Comment: Try not use a `location.reload`: it's better call a funciton initialize or similar. a location.reload, load all the app

Comment: is there any event function like ngOninit which fires when the back button is clicked?

Comment: This doesn't trigger in Chrome using Angular 14 for me

Comment: @Ste you might want to use a listener on ActivatedRoute as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68754029/13497139. Instead of subscribing to params, I've subscibed to the url, and that works great to catch a backpress.

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to enrich @bmorgs answer. Tested below in Angular 15. Using it like this the page will still feel like an SPA instead of doing a hard refresh in the browser.

```js
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private router: Router) {}

@HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
onPopState(event) {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(`${window.location.pathname}`, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    skipLocationChange: true,
  });
}
```