# Angular routing doesn't refresh the page

Tags: angular

I want to be able to change data on my page based on the URL route, i.e. test/1 gets me data set 1, test/2 gets me data set 2. However if i am already on test/1 and try to navigate to test/2 (and vice versa) using router navigate, it changes the url but that's it, nothing else gets triggered.

I have following definition for my route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'test',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: TestComponent
      },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]
  },
];
```

TS Component:

```
value: any;

constructor(private router: Router, private, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
   this.value = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
}

goToPage(value: any) {
    this.router.navigate(['/test', value]);
}
```

my html component:

```
{{value}}

<button (click)="goToPage(1)">One</button>
<button (click)="goToPage(2)">Two</button>
```

I've also tried adding { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' } to RouterModule.forRoot, still doesn't do anything.

NOTE:
Problem is not to get the parameter, the problem is the refresh of the page that has to take place to trigger all processes associated with the new parameter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Option 1: Listen to route changes and initialize page

```
constructor(private router: Router, private, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.value = this.route.snapshot.params.id; // for first entry
   route.params.subscribe(val => {
     this.value = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
     // put the code to initialize the page
   });

}
```

### Option 2: Reinitialize the page on route navigation

```
goToPage(value: any) {
    this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function () {
        return false;
    }
    this.router.onSameUrlNavigation = 'reload';
    this.router.navigate(['/test', value]);
}
```

Comment: The 'routeReuseStrategy' is deprecated.

Comment: Option 2 is the best as option 1 caused flashing. I was on Angular 8 so deprecation not an issue.

Answer (score 11):

Resolved the problem by implementing the following code:

```
    this.router.navigate(['/test', value])
        .then(() => {
          window.location.reload();
        });
```

Comment: Lovely stuff over here... I spent 3 hours trying to figure out... And the solution is so dope. Just to simply Go with the reload functionality to the next page... #Claps

Comment: YEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Comment: Well. because the alternative is to subscribe to a change event of the active route or something. Btw reloading a while Angular application is NOT the right way to do this.. Since this will definitely cause performance issues on the client-side.

Comment: Terrible user experience. Does work though.

Comment: If you store state in your singletons (services) this will nuke all the state.

Answer (score 2):

For it to be able to refresh the data, this piece of code `this.value = this.route.snapshot.params.id` should be called in `ngOnInit()` in this manner:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      param => {
        this.value = param['id']
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yep already across that method but how does that solve refresh of the page problem?

Comment: The refreshing is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63612473/11156095)

Comment: Will this not subscribe every-time to the param change event in the ngOnInit() method? Since this method is called if you go to this page every time again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting params from `this.value = this.route.snapshot.params.id` you can subscribe the `paramMap` and get the `id`

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
  (params: ParamMap) => {
    const id = params.get('id');

    // call your api etc to get the record against new id
  }
);
```

Comment: Yep already across that method but how does that solve refresh of the page problem?

Comment: @Aeseir it subscribe each time when route change and you will have a new route value, I believe I posted this answer first so you should have accept my attempt :) anyways you can upvote though

Comment: @KamranKhatti you need to add this piece of code to the constructor and not to ngOnInit()

Answer (score 0):

My full solution using the `subscribe()` method, in TS with Angular:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'
import { Params, Router } from '@angular/router'
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router'
import { Location } from '@angular/common'
import { UserService } from '../user.service'
import { User } from '../user.model'
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs'

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
    user$: Observable<User> = of({} as User)
    id: number | undefined = 0

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private userService: UserService,
        private location: Location
    ) {
        this.id = this.route.snapshot.params.id
        // Listen on change event for ID parameter
        this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params) => {
          this.id = params['id']
          this.loadDetails() // triggered when pressing the button
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadDetails() // Initial load during page load
    }

    changePage(userId: number) {
        this.router.navigate(['user/detail', userId])
    }

    private loadDetails() {
        const id = (this.id) ? +this.id : 0 // Zero should fail
        this.user$ = this.userService.getOne(id) // Your service or API or...
    }
}
```

HTML template:

```
<button mat-raised-button type="submit" (click)="changePage(user.id)">BLabla</button>
```