# Angular route refresh the URL but page was not getting refresh

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using [routerLink] to navigate routers. But it is not working as expected. After click on the link URL got changed but page was not getting refresh.

My Code:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/list/contentpage'" [queryParams]="{ id: item.id }">{{ item.title }}</a>
```

Comment: Can you try the following? `[routerLink]=['/list/contentpage']` 
...and can you share your app-routing.module.ts?

Comment: you should check your router module configuration. or drop the snippet

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are possibly on a version of that route already but changing the query parameter and the data isn't refreshing.

This other stack overflow Q/A is exactly that scenario.

[Angular routing doesn't refresh the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68753614/angular-routing-doesnt-refresh-the-page)

```
constructor(private router: Router, private, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
   this.value = this.route.snapshot.params.id; // for first entry
   route.params.subscribe(val => {
     this.value = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
     // put the code to initialize the page
   });

}
```